# Thumbnail upload - Request forbidden by administrative rules

Tags: vimeo-api

Following this tutorial -> https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/thumbnails
I have setup a time of 180s and the request of step 2 has returned status 201.
all the links have a similar format: 
`https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/<id>_<size>.jpg?r=pad'`
Here is the request:

```
{ protocol: 'https:',
  host: 'i.vimeocdn.com',
  port: 443,
  method: 'PUT',
  headers:
   { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
     Accept: 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
     'User-Agent': 'Vimeo.js/2.1.1',
     Authorization: 'Bearer 9a3918a750089766b46f0e8a59a79f49',
     'Content-Length': 189 },
  body:
   '_readableState=&readable=true&_events=&_eventsCount=1&_maxListeners=&path=%2Ffile.jpg&fd=&flags=r&mode=438&start=&end=&autoClose=true&pos=&bytesRead=0&closed=false',
  path: '/video/<id>_1920x1080.jpg' }
}
```

I've tried with that URI but allways get this result:

```
<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>

{ connection: 'close',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'text/html',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes, bytes',
  via: '1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  date: 'Wed, 10 Jun 2020 16:59:05 GMT',
  'x-served-by': 'cache-dfw18638-DFW, cache-ewr18125-EWR',
  'x-cache': 'MISS, MISS',
  'x-cache-hits': '0, 0',
  'x-timer': 'S1591808345.129097,VS0,VE49',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }
```

The token has the following access: 
`private create edit upload video_files public`

I've tried to do the *PUT* request to the api hostname, but the page couldn't be found.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the wrong link, the PUT request must be to a link that looks like this:
`https://i.cloud.vimeo.com/video/<id>?expires=<timestamp>&sig=<hash>`